# How to use CMake to build sources with ghdl as custom target?

Tags: cmake, ghdl

I would like to build VHDL sources with CMake. For this I have a directory structure:

```
   <root>
      -  CMakeLists.txt
      -  src/CMakeLists.txt
      -  src/mymodule.vhdl
      -  build
```

Inside the root CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(vhdlsdb LANGUAGES NONE)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

In the src/CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
set(filelist mymodule.vhdl )
add_custom_target(vhdlize COMMAND ghdl -a ${filelist})
```

However, when I run cd build && cmake .. -GNinja && cmake --build . --target vhdlize I get:

```
     error: cannot open mymodule
     C:\Users\pm\git\GHDL\0.36-mingw64-llvm\bin\ghdl.exe: compilation error
```

How can I tell CMake to copy or look for the sources in the src folder?

Comment: "How can I tell CMake to copy or look for the sources in the src folder?" - Use **absolute path** to the file: `set(filelist ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mymodule.vhdl )`. Or specify `WORKING_DIRECTORY` for the custom target, so the command will be run with this directory being current.

Comment: thanks that works indeed with the cmake_current_source_dir variable set